# How to download multiple photos from OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, photos, nokia-lumia-620

I have uploaded many photos to OneDrive from my Lumia 620 phone.

I accidentally deleted all my photos from the phone, but thankfully OneDrive has a backup of them.

I want to download all of the photos from OneDrive to my Phone, but there is no option to select all photos at once and then download them all. I am able to download a single photo by tapping on it, but it's very lengthy process because I have uploaded around 1000 photos. That means I need to open 1000 photos one by one and download them.

Is there any way to download all photos in single click?

Comment: The nearest solution I can think about is download them and transfer via cable to your phone.

Comment: @VitorCanova yes it is the way so there is no meaning to use skydrive for download means it's use for to give it(how batter it auto upload images) but when we want to take back from it then hesitate (take one by one not bunch of images) :). really skydrive annoying me and alternatively windows.

Comment: Why do you need to download 1000 photos to *your phone* again? These could be accessed via the OneDrive app as needed, or from any PC (which also has a "download folder" option).

Comment: @RowlandShaw For the access photos from oneDrive i need to be online but i would to like see photos offline after downloading them.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can download multiple photos at once:

1. On your phone open IE, go to https://onedrive.live.com and log in to your OneDrive account.
2. At the bottom click the "PC site" link to get the full desktop version.
3. Open the folder that contains the photos you want to download.
4. Then go to "Folder options" and select "Download folder".

Now the file will be downloaded as a zip file, so you need an app to extract the file which you can find in the store.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest update to the OneDrive app (version 4.2), you can now download multiple files from OneDrive to your phone. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Open the OneDrive app
2. Navigate to the folder where the files you want to download are located
3. Tap the "select" icon in the app bar
4. Tap on each of the files you want to download to mark them
5. Tap the "download" icon in the app bar
6. Select a folder on your phone and tap OK
7. The files will now be downloaded in the background

For more information, see [this article at WPCentral.com](http://www.wpcentral.com/onedrive-update-windows-phone-download-location-choice-progress-page-and-more).

Answer (score 1):

You should sync OneDrive on your computer and transfer them to your phone. Its only a one time task, so I would suggest you go about this way and regularly sync OneDrive the computer so that you always have offline content on it.

Comment: So..only window phone is not enough right? need support  of PC.Really it's totally wastage of time and money.

Comment: Yes. Windows Phone is not enough. You do need PC support.

Comment: I think sync needed two way means when new photo i add in phone then it will sync with oneDrive and uploaded to on oneDrive. Now if that new photo deleted from phone then it should be sync from oneDrive means downloaded automatically from oneDrive.

Comment: @jayesh, so If I have 50 GB of content on OneDrive, which I do, I need to have the same amount of storage available on the phone? Also, talking of definitions of sync, do you really mean what you are saying? What happens if you do not want a copy on the device? Please note that sync and mirroring are different concepts, because what you are saying can be logically extended to mean that any deletions on OneDrive should automatically delete content from the phone as well. Acceptable?